# Cannot find way to mount gfi outlet in 4 inch box with cover

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

I have a 4 inch square  box. Need to replace the duplex outlet with a GFI. Removed the cover for the duplex outlet,replaced it with the  GFI but had to add an extension ring as the box was too shallow. The GFI outlet mounting ears have nothing to grab to. The single rectangle cutout cover does not line up with the GFI screws either. How do I secure the GFI in the box? Does this require    threaded holes along the ring?

Comment: How about a picture of what you've got there.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways those boxes can be configured - corner screws, or "standard location for 2-gang outlets" screws.  We need to have a looksy at the arrangement for the particular box and extension box you acquired.  It's definitely doable; I do it all the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/128427/18078

Answer (score 8):

You need a one (or two, and put in an outlet on the load side, even) space **exposed work** cover if you are working with a bare box mounted on the wall:

[image: one-space exposed work cover Image from Zoro.com]

[image: two-space exposed work cover Image from Zoro.com]

If the box is IN the wall, then you need a mud (plaster) ring:

[image: mud (plaster) ring Image from Zoro.com]

*Images are from Zoro.com, no endorsement implied.*

The holes are in different places between the two, as the "exposed work cover" screws in with different screw holes (the device goes in from the **back** of the cover and is held to it by the screws, and normally the ears have to be snapped off to fit for a 4" box (not so much on a 4-11/16 box.) Normally there are nuts, washers and screws provided with the cover, rather than the cover holes being threaded.

The "Mud ring" has the threaded device holes for mounting a device that you expect in a wall box, The device mounts to the **front** of it, and then you mount a Decora trim cover plate to make things nice.

You can mount a plaster ring and a trim plate on an exposed box, but it's clumsy and prone to damage, as the corners of the trim plate stick out and catch things.